# Categorizing columns by percentiles from two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, percentile

I have two tables containing data about users.

I need to create 3 groups of users, divided by percentiles of columns from both table.

table_1:

| user_no | matches |
| --- | --- |
| 3354 | 5 |
| 45744 | 30 |
| 21421 | 12 |
| 20121 | 50 |
| 21254 | 8 |
| 21454 | 2 |

table_2:

| user_no | level |
| --- | --- |
| 3354 | 128 |
| 45744 | 37 |
| 21421 | 25 |
| 20121 | 11 |
| 21254 | 77 |
| 21454 | 3 |

My purpose is to present in the end the `user_no` and new column called `division` which is determined from the average percentile from both tables.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely wrong, but it's a start.

> ```
> create table table_1 (
>  user_no int primary key not null, 
>  matches int not null
> );
>
> create table table_2 (
>  user_no int primary key not null, 
>  level int not null
> );
>
> insert into table_1 
> (user_no,     matches) values
>   (3354,      5) 
> , (45744,     30) 
> , (21421,     12) 
> , (20121,     50) 
> , (21254,     8) 
> , (21454,     2);
>
> insert into table_2 
> (user_no,     level) values
>   (3354,      128) 
> , (45744,     37) 
> , (21421,     25) 
> , (20121,     11) 
> , (21254,     77) 
> , (21454,     3);
> ```

> ```
> select user_no, matches, level
> , round((perc_matches+perc_level)/2, 2) as perc
> , ntile(3) over (order by (perc_matches+perc_level)/2 desc) division
> from
> (
>     select *
>     , round(100.0*matches/sum(matches) over(), 2) perc_matches
>     , round(100.0*level/sum(level) over(), 2) perc_level
>     from table_1
>     join table_2 using(user_no)
> ) q
> ```
>
> ```
> user_no | matches | level |  perc | division
> ------: | ------: | ----: | ----: | -------:
>   20121 |      50 |    11 | 25.32 |        1
>    3354 |       5 |   128 | 25.11 |        1
>   45744 |      30 |    37 | 20.61 |        2
>   21254 |       8 |    77 | 17.44 |        2
>   21421 |      12 |    25 | 10.06 |        3
>   21454 |       2 |     3 |  1.47 |        3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8ef50dd8789852ceb77359014251b866)*